# Drawing lines on top and bottom on figures

Tags: line

I would like to create a figure with one line on top of it, and another one at the bottom, that separate the figure form the text. I have tried using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{capacidad_campo.png}
    \caption{Diagrama que muestra los diferentes posibles estados sobre la capacidad de campo del suelo. Fuente: \url{http://www.soilwater.com.au/laboratory.html}}
    \par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}
\end{figure}
```

The bottom line works just fine, but the top line gets stuck to the figure image, and the vspace is just separating the image from the caption.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this what you want: `\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}\par\medskip`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{0.1pt}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{capacidad_campo.png}
\caption{Diagrama que muestra los diferentes posibles estados sobre la capacidad de campo del suelo. Fuente: \protect\url{http://www.soilwater.com.au/laboratory.html}}
\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{0.1pt}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]